# How can I check to see if the current user has an an order in checkout?

Tags: commerce

I need to create a condition like the following:

```
 if (current user has an order in checkout){
    go to the checkout page
 }else{
    go to this other page
 }
```

So far, I'm using:

```
 if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid)) {
      drupal_goto('checkout/')
 }else{
      drupal_goto('someotherpage/')
 }
```

but it doesn't seem to work. What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: There is probably a good way to do this in Rules, and make absolutely sure you need that drupal_goto..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Preload `$user` variable.
- Remove those `/` at the end of each url.
- Add a semicolon at the end of each PHP line.

  ```
  global $user;
  if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid)) {
    drupal_goto('checkout');
  }
  else {
    drupal_goto('someotherpage');
  }
  ```